# Working with Protobuf Kafka messages from Hive

Tags: apache-kafka, hive, protocol-buffers

Regular (JSON) Kafka topics can be easily connected to Hive as external tables, like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE
  dummy_table (
    `field1` BIGINT,
    `field2` STRING,
    `field3` STRING
    )
STORED BY
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.kafka.KafkaStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  "kafka.topic" = "dummy_topic",
  "kafka.bootstrap.servers" = "dummybroker:9092")
```

But what about Protobuf encoded topics? Can they be connected, too? I wasn't able to find any examples of this on the net.

If yes - how (where) in code should .Proto file be specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to add `kafka.serde.class` to the properties.

Assuming you're using Confluent Schema Registry w/ Proto messages, [only Avro is supported](https://github.com/apache/hive/tree/master/kafka-handler#usage)

Otherwise, there was an old project called [Elephant-Bird](https://github.com/twitter/elephant-bird) for adding Protobuf support to Hive. I'm not sure if it still works, or can be used for the Kafka Serde config. But assuming it can, your Proto file would need to be placed in HDFS, for example, and gathered by each Hive map task

Comment: Thanks, man!
I'm aware of `kafka.serde.class` property, but can't figure out what should be placed there for decoding Protobuf messages. Isn't there any code example, by any chance?

Comment: Out of the box, there's no serde for Protobuf

Comment: You'd need to compile the elephant-bird project, then you can try using that... https://github.com/twitter/elephant-bird/wiki/How-to-use-Elephant-Bird-with-Hive

Comment: The alternative is read as bytes, then use a custom UDF to define deserialize functions like Spark does

Comment: That's sad, man. I hoped for some pure HiveQL solution. Hive works nicely with regular JSON messages, didn't think Protobuf required digging into Java. Sure, I'll try Elephant-Bird, it looks promising, although kinda overkill.
Thank you very much anyway! If nothing else pops up real soon, I'll accept it as a final answer.